# Limit of numerical sequence $\lim_{n\to\infty} (n^{(-1)^n}) $ and is it bounded?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Can someone please explain me how to find limit of numerical sequence

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} (n^{(-1)^n}) $$

As of first part of question I am clueless how to do it. When I run it on online calculators they say limit doesn't exists. Is it so?

And is numerical sequence $ x_n = n^{(-1)^n} $ bounded?

As of second part of question when I write down elements of this sequence I get:

$$ 1, 2, \frac{1}{3}, 4, \frac{1}{5}, 6, \frac{1}{7}, 8, \frac{1}{9}, 10, \ldots $$

So far as I can see not one member gets below $0$ so lower boundary is $0$, right? So we can say numerical sequence is bounded below. Is it true?

Comment: we have $$(-1)^n=1$$ if $n$ is even and $$(-1)^n=-1$$ if $n$ is odd

Comment: Is there a reason why someone down-voted this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$0$ is a lower bound of this sequence, and it is the largest of all lower bounds of this sequence. There is no upper bound for reasons you appear to know already.

That there can be no larger lower bound that $0$ follows from the fact that the set of reciprocals of those fractions, $1/3,\ 1/5,\ 1/7,\ 1/9,\text{ etc.},$ has no upper bound.

Since there is no upper bound, the sequence is unbounded and therefore does not have a limit.

Answer (score 3):

For each even number $n$, $x_n=n^1=n$. Therefore, the sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is unbounded. And every convergent sequence is bounded. Therefore, the sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ does not converge.

Answer (score 1):

We have $$\limsup_{n \to \infty}n^{(-1)^n} = +\infty \qquad \text{and} \qquad \liminf_{n \to \infty}n^{(-1)^n} = 0$$ hence the sequence does not converge and is unbounded.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, the sequence contains arbitrarily large elements, since the subsequence $(x_{2m})_{m\in\mathbb N}$ is unbounded. This is because $x_{2m} = 2m$, which gets arbitrarily large. A convergent sequence needs to be bounded. Since this sequence isn't bounded, it cannot converge.

It is true that $0$ is a lower bound, indeed it is the infimum. Since all elements of the sequence are positive, $0$ is a lower bound. To show that it is the largest lower bound, we note that the subsequence $(x_{2n+1})_{n\in\mathbb N}$ approaches zero:
For any $\epsilon > 0$ we have $x_{2n+1} < \epsilon$ iff $2n+1>\frac 1\epsilon$, which is equivalent to $n>\frac{1-\epsilon}{2\epsilon}$. I.e., for sufficently large $n$ the sequence approaches zero closer than $\epsilon$.